# gulp-concat is not transforming my jsx files to js with reactify

Tags: express, gulp, browserify, jsx, reactify

I'm new to Gulp and I'm trying to transform my jsx files to js files using browserify and reactify but I'm getting and error. My gulp file looks like this:

```js
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    nodemon = require('gulp-nodemon'),
    browserify = require('browserify'),
    reactify = require('reactify'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),

gulp.task('bundler', function() {
    gulp.src('public/javascript/app.jsx')
        .pipe(browserify({
            transform: 'reactify',
            extensions: ['.jsx']
        }))
        .pipe(concat('main.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/javascript'));
});

gulp.task('server', function() {
    nodemon({
        script: 'server.js',
        ext: 'html js',
        watch: 'public'})
        .on('restart', function() {
            console.log('Restarted');
        });
});

gulp.task('default', ['bundler', 'server']);
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: gulp.src(...).pipe(...).pipe is not a function
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (/Users/H/WebstormProjects/royalp/gulpfile.js:16:10)
    at module.exports (/Users/H/WebstormProjects/royalp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:34:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (/Users/H/WebstormProjects/royalp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:273:3)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (/Users/H/WebstormProjects/royalp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:214:10)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (/Users/H/WebstormProjects/royalp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:134:8)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp-cli/index.js:133:20
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:433:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:362:13)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:433:11)
    at startup (node.js:141:18)
/Users/H/WebstormProjects/royalp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:523
    dest.end();
         ^

TypeError: dest.end is not a function
    at DestroyableTransform.onend (/Users/H/WebstormProjects/royalp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:523:10)
    at DestroyableTransform.g (events.js:261:16)
    at emitNone (events.js:73:20)
    at DestroyableTransform.emit (events.js:167:7)
    at /Users/H/WebstormProjects/royalp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:965:16
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:433:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:362:13)
```

It was working fine before but all of a sudden it stopped working. I've been trying to fix it for hours now but I cant find the reason why it's not working, I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: The `bundler` gulp task looks fine to me, do you happen to know what you have changed prior to noticing it stopped working? (upgraded dependencies, moving around folders, etc)

Comment: No, i didn't change anything :( but when i change the second line of bundler task to './public/javascript/*.jsx' the error says "TypeError: dest.write is not a function"

Comment: Both errors indicate there is no stream to write to, which means either `gulp.src(..)`, `browserify(..)` or `concat(..)` does not properly provide a stream. From the `dest.write` we can conclude that is at least a transform stream, which rules out `gulp.src`. I'd comment out the `.pipe(concat(..))` line, so see if the error goes away, so if it does, you know it is the `concat` you need to focus on, if the error persists, `browserify(..)` is the culprit.

Comment: Yeah, browserify was the problem. I searched online and found a better way to transform my jsx, thank you! :)

Comment: @corosan: mind sharing the alternate solution  you found? I ended up using gulp-jsx, but ran into a Parse error (within the library .. not in my gulpfile)

Comment: @Prashant  https://gist.github.com/corasan/8572cdd3bd606c7b6b58 this is the one I used.